# Using remainder in C with two positive doubles turns it to negative?

Tags: c, modulo

I am just starting to learn C programming but whenever I run this:

```
double a = 9.92; 
double b = 2.00;
printf("%.2lf,  %.2lf,  %.2lf", a, b, remainder(a, b));
```

The output is always $-0.18. The output that I was hoping for is $1.92.

Comment: What is this remainder function? Normally you would just use a % b.

Comment: It looks like your `remainder()` function is rounding the quotient to the nearest integer. That will make `9.92/2.00` round up to `5`. rather than down to `4`. Then when it gets the remainder, it's negative.

Comment: The docs for math.h's `remainder` suggests using `fmod` if you want the sign of the remainder to be the same as the first argument's

Comment: @Alex: This remainder function is the C standard library function `remainder`, specified in C 2018 7.12.10.2. The `%` operator will not work with `double` operands.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Totally right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remainder function rounds the result of the division to the nearest integer, which means you can get a negative result.  From the man page:

> The  `remainder()`  function  computes  the remainder of dividing `x`
> by `y`.    The return value is `x-n*y`, where `n` is the value `x / y`,
> rounded  to  the    nearest integer.  If the absolute value of `x-n*y`
> is 0.5, `n` is chosen to    be even.

So given your input, `9.92 / 2` results in `4.96` which rounded to the nearest integer is `5`.  Then you have `9.92 - (5 * 2.00)` == `9.92 - 10.0` == `-0.08`.

You want to instead use `fmod`, which rounds the division toward 0.  The man page for that states:

> The `fmod()` function computes the floating-point remainder of
> dividing `x`    by `y`.  The return value is `x - n * y`, where `n` is the
> quotient of `x / y`,    rounded toward zero to an integer.

Comment: To further clarify this answer: `n` is `9.92 / 2.00` rounded to the closest integer, so `4.96` => `5`. Now `9.92 - 5 * 2.00` equals to `-0.08`. The `-0.18` might be a typo by OP.

Comment: @Cheatah Good point.  I've included it in the answer.